# How can I make an HTML button affect the data of a python script when pressed?

Tags: python, html, button, flask, python-requests

I'm generating an HTML page via Python, using the Flask framework to receive messages and the requests module to send them. My python script has a global list variable called `History`, and when a button is clicked I want the python script to run the command `History = []` (e.g. dump the contents of the list).

How do i achieve that? I generated the button with the following code :

```
s += '<input type="submit" value="Reset History">'
return s
```

But right now it does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the HTML page send a value using either POST or GET, which is then picked up by a cgi form in Python, converted to integer, and

```
<input type="submit" name="reset_hist" />
```

---

```
if(reset_hist):
    History = []
```

---

Or you could use AJAX to send the request, instead of loading a new page. see `xmlHttpRequest()`